# Crash while changing value of a NSMutableDictioanary

Tags: ios, swift3, nsarray, nsdictionary

I need some help with NSMutableDictionary inside NSArray in Swift 3.0. 
The structure is an Array of Dictionaries

This is my code

```
class abc{
    var myTempArr : NSArray! 
 }

  // I need objC variables as I need to pass them as reference

 someMethod(){
    myTempArr = [["title":"abc","id":"1"]] // creating a dictionary inside the array
   // I have changed the value like this also, but the crash remains
   // [["title":"abc","id":"1"] as! NSMutableDictionary]


 }


// This method is called in every key stroke in keyboard. Lets say we replace the "title", with the letter in the keyboard it is tapped

 func someotherMethod(){
      let firstDictionary = myTempArr[0] as! NSMutableDictionary
      // Its crashing here!!!!
      // Again i need nsmutabledictionary as i need to change the value
      // inside the dictionary so that the value inside the main array
      // that is myTempArr also changes. I need a pass by reference
      // method, hence i choosed NSMutableDictionary instead of swift dictionary

      firstDictionary["title"] = "New Title"
      // After this line, the original dictionary inside myTempArr
      // should change as well. But its crashing in the mentioned line

 }
```

I dont want to use class instances as I know they are also pass by reference but I need to apply Predicate to finding the correct dictionary inside the array, instead of searching by index. This is also a concept I cannot understand. Please help me figure this out.

The crash says :

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSDictionary' 
>       (0x7facdb71e6c0) to 'NSMutableDictionary' (0x102bfa350).

**[EDIT]**

As many people are suggesting the option of getting the Dictionary in a variable, changing the variable and then replacing the dictionary in the array. Well this approach I want to avoid, as this would be the same as using value based solution (Swift Dictionary where its passed by value). The reason I want to avoid this is because, the original DS I am using has a huge number of dictionaries and values of dictionary are changing very often. Hence I dont think using the replace Dictionary approach would be sound.

Also I know in swift this is not good, as swift was NOT designed for this. This approach works perfectly fine in Objective C, as we changing variables (cue : Pointers of variables), changes the variable it was originally from. 
If anyone can suggest an alternate or good approach in Swift, then please It would be awesome.

Also for the sake of simplicity I have used an index of 0. as there is only 1 dictionary. But in the original DS, there are a lot of dictionaries as I mentioned, hence I am using predicate. This is also a reason why I didnt use instance of a class (also pass by reference in swift), as I dont know if instances of class behave like dictionaries when we search them by Predicate.

Any solution or alternative is highly welcome. As always thank you guys for giving time to this, as I am trying to wrap my head around how to go for a new approach

Comment: If you want an `NSMutableDictionary` then you will need to explicitly create one, but if you have a function that relies on side effects then you should probably reconsider your design.  Using immutability gives more robust code.

Comment: Yes I agree, immutability is the way to go, 
But I need to deal with a form that is powered by a Data structure with array of dictionaries. Now everytime I edit anything in the dictionary via that form, I need to change the exact value of the dictionary. Now this design approach does NOT go with Swift. But it would be nice if you can suggest any other design or model. But till now I need to fix this

Comment: Use a custom class rather than a dictionary and Swift `Array`. That gives you reference semantics, too. Whenever you can avoid `NSMutableArray / -Dictionary` in Swift, do it !

Comment: Will predicate on custom class work, as they work on dictionaries in swift? 
As you can understand I am new to swift so pardon on asking such a question

Comment: Of course it will, but it's recommended to use also the native functions like `filter`.

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information on what `someOtherMethod` is trying to do to propose a better solution.

Comment: editing accordingly @Paulw11

Comment: It seems like a dictionary is probably the wrong choice of item to store in  your array.  Assuming that the array contains data on form fields where each field contains something like an `id`, a `name` and a `value`, you could use an array of objects with these properties.    The array and your variable with the result of the predicate search will refer to the same object and you can mutate the `value` as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that a dictionary is probably the wrong data structure to store in your array.  You have indicated that the dictionaries represent some sort of form fields.  You can create an object to model these fields and then take advantage of the mutability of objects while still using immutable arrays.

Something like:

```
class Field {

    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var value: String

    init(id: Int, name: String, value: String = "") {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }

}

let firstNameField = Field(id:1, name:"FirstName")
let surnameField = Field(id:2, name:"Surname")

firstNameField.value = "Paul"

var fieldsArray = [firstNameField,surnameField]

firstNameField.value = "Peter"

print(fieldsArray[0].value)  // Prints Peter

if let field1 = fieldsArray.first(where:{ $0.id == 1} ) {    
    print(field1.value)  // Prints Peter
    field1.value = "John"
}

print(fieldsArray[0].value)  // Prints John
```

Note that since `Field` is a class we were able to use reference semantics and never had to mutate the array, so there were no copy on modify operations on the array.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, I need to predicate search all the instances for say some key in the var `id`. Will that be possible? Or rather would that me more efficient if the changes are happening quite often. Is there any other approach for this type of problem?

Comment: That is what I have shown with the `where` statement. If you know which attribute you want to search by, however, it is probably more efficient to create a dictionary of fields keyed by the search attribute as searching a dictionary is O(logn) while searching an array is O(n). There may be other optimisations possible too. You can identify the field when it becomes the first responder so there is no need to continually search the array; you can hold a reference to the current field until another field is selected.

Comment: thanks for the tip. There are certain more design pattern I want to discuss with you, regarding swift 3, if possible and thanks again for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let firstDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: myTempArr[0])
```

Comment: This would not change the main array `myTempArr`, when i change anything in the `firstDictionary` in this process

Comment: then you need to replace the old dictionary with `firstDictionary` inside `myTempArr`.

Comment: Cannot do that, as the array I am working with is huge and any event change can happen in almost all events on the data structure i.e in every keyboard button tap. Hence cannot go by replace logic. Please suggest me something else , do appreciate the time u guys are giving me :)

Comment: Your main array `myTempArr` is NSArray which is immutable. Even if you get the instance of the dictionary from that array it will be immutable. As Paulw11 said you need to reconsider your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Because that dictionary is not mutable. You cannot cast it as such.
You might wanna do something like this:

EDIT: Okay this should work for you then:

```
var tempArray: Array<Dictionary<String,String>>!
```

Initialize...

```
tempArray = [["title":"abc","id":"1"]]
```

And edit the dictionary like so:

```
func someotherMethod(){ 
     tempArray[0]["title"] = "New Title" 
}
```

EDIT:
I don't know - listening to your comments, maybe something like this will work for you?

About your question regarding getting the correct dictionary:

DOUBLE EDIT:

```
if let dictionaryIndex = tempArray.index(where: {$0["title"] == "abc"}) {
        tempArray[dictionaryIndex]["title"] = "NOT ABC"
}
```

Boomtown. You get the exact dictionary you want with that == check, and you change the exact mutable tempArray value.

Comment: Why a downvote? I agree downcasting + using NS classes in swift isn't the best option, but it is what the question was about.

Comment: I already casted it as NSMutableDictionary and its crashing at that line only.
Also, making this approach, the main array would not change.
Always replacing the dictionary is NOT an option, as this is a demo array, it might contain thousands of dictionary inside and it might change in say : every key stroke.

Comment: Please read my comment, as I wrote what is wrong with this approach

Comment: Cannot go by this, as I need to catch the EXACT dictionary with another variable, as I am using predicate to filter THAT Exact dictionary instead of INDEX. Thus applying your code to that logic, the problem persists

Comment: In your question you used index of 0, so I did in mine. You wanted to change the title of the dictionary at index 0 , and my code does that.
If this doesn't solve your problem, maybe you should add onto your question, what you actually need help with.  Ran my code through playground works exactly what you put in your question.

Comment: I see your still posting comments, and saying you don't want to replace the dictionary each time, which my answer works best for you. 
The only difference betwen this code and the one you said would "work for you" is 1. It has a let statement to reference that dictionary (why would you even need this, just use the direct dictionary like in my answer ie. temparray[ 0] instead of firstDictionary) 2. In my version you are avoiding all the negatives of having NS classes in Swift. - Which you should always try and avoid. Ah well...

Comment: I need a variable to hold the dictionary, as for simplicity sake i had only 1 dictionary in the array, hence we know the index as 0. But in my main data structure, there are a lot of dictionaries, so I have to run a predicate to get the actual dictionary that I want to change. hence I need a variable to hold the dictionary first, before changing it

Answer (score 0):

You can define the myTempArr in this way:

```
func someMethod(){
    let nsmutabledict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: ["title":"abc","id":"1"])
    myTempArr = [nsmutabledict]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind for crashing your code is `NSArray`, need to change into `NSMutableArray` because subscripts not supporting with `NSArray` for Mutable behavior.

---

**Check below code and do changes inside your code after it will work: -**

```
var myTempArr: NSMutableArray = [["title":"abc","id":"1"]] //Should be mutable for updating information
let dictionary = myTempArr[0] as? NSMutableDictionary ?? [:] //Getting here dictionay(Key value here)
dictionary["title"] = "New Title"  //Changing here value
myTempArr[0] = dictionary  //Finally updating on main array details
```

---

#### Otherwise, can try below code: -

```
var array = [["title":"abc","id":"1"]] //Mutable Array
var dictionary = myTempArr[0] as? [String: String] ?? [:] //Getting here values
dictionary["title"] = "New Title" //Changing value
myTempArr[0] = dictionary // Updating Main array value
```

---

#### Output of codes: -

[image: Output]

Comment: This cannot work. You cannot create a `NSMutableArray` from a literal just be annotating the type. And you cannot cast anything to `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift.

Comment: I have just converted a type of data for explaining.  @vadian

Comment: `NSMutable...` collection types are hopeless in Swift because they are not related and cannot be casted to the native Swift counterparts.

Comment: I know all things related swift but please check my answer once i have added new thing there. @vadian

Comment: This would work, But as i said, I cannot go on replacing the dictionary that is being changed in the main array. I want a passed by reference solution, where a change in the variable of the dictionary would push the original change in the array itself.

Comment: Yes, we can do as per our knowledge but here I have to give two-way solutions but this depends on the developer.  @SahebRoy

Comment: @SahebRoy, please change your `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` then try will work.There subscripts not available with `NSArray` for updating values.

Comment: I have changed but the problem is still persisting. 
Also, a call by reference approach would not require the main DS to be mutable/immutable.

As i said, `NSMutableArray` would be needed when I am replacing the dictionary in the array. In this case `NSArray` would be suffice